# Where do I throw the exception?

Tags: php, arrays, exception, loops, foreach

I have the following php function that renders an array of templates based on an array of paths. In other words, if you provide a set of arrays such as:

```
$array_template = array(
    'carousel' => 'carousel', //type=>name (with out extension).
    'mini' => 'mini_feed'
)

$array_paths = array(
    'path_one' => 'path/to/one/',
    'path_two' => 'path/to/two/'
)
```

To this function:

```
protected function _render_templates_array($templates, array $template_name){
    foreach($template_name as $type=>$name){
        foreach($templates as $template=>$path){
            if(file_exists($path . $name . '.phtml')){
                require_once($path . $name . '.phtml');
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

It should find and render every file, checking every path for that file.

The problem I am having is, I figured out how to make it stop searching once all files are found, how ever, do I append an else to the if and throw my error? or is there some where else I should throw my error?

Essentially I need:

1. render all templates, making sure to look in all paths for those templates.
2. throw an error if the template is not found in any path.
3. stop processing once all files are loaded.

Thoughts?

Comment: It all depends on what your application needs to do. If you can cope with not finding a template, go ahead and continue with the other templates. If finding the templates is fundamental, and you can't find one, then stop and throw an exception. Purely your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between the two `foreach` lines, add `$found = false;`. Inside the `if`, add `$found = true;` Between the two "end foreach" `}`, add `if(!$found) throw.....;` as needed.

```
protected function _render_templates_array($templates, array $template_name){
    foreach($template_name as $type=>$name){
        $found = false;
        foreach($templates as $template=>$path){
            if(file_exists($path . $name . '.phtml')){
                require_once($path . $name . '.phtml');
                $found = true;
            }
        }
        if( !$found) throw new .......;
    }

    return;
}
```